# Setup for Team Foundation and ClearCase with TFS Integration Tool

Tags: tfs, clearcase, tfsintegrationplatform

I want to do daily migration of TFS changes to a ClearCase system. I was going to try out TFS Integration tools but I can't get any of the toolset pieces to work. What are the requirements to run this app? I have VS 2010, TFS 2010 and Sharepoint 2010 installed. The assemblies it's trying to load don't seem to be present in VS2010 and I don't if it requires VS 2008 or not. Anyone ever had this running? I'm migrating from TFS to CC. Not the other way around.

Update:

I've been using this tool to sync TFS 2010 changes back into a UCM ClearCase implementation at the client. It has been going poorly. The tool should be clearly marked as Beta or even Alpha. A peek into the code reveal around 100 TODO's and "This needs to be fixed". I have spent a good deal of time trying to iron out some of the issues and have made progress. My suggestion is before using this tool on mission critical projects, spend at least 3-4 weeks evaluating it in your environment. When it works, it works pretty well with moving changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided to go with the [TFS Integration Platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/). It allows us to sync TFS work items back into ClearCase when ever we want. It provides the level of integration we needed to keep the traceability. The TFS to CC integration is bleeding edge, but it works enough for what we need. (Syncing work items and user check ins.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about how to access TFS2010 elements, besides ["check an individual project for pre & postbuild steps either by loading the project in visual studio or manually reading the project file"](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfsbuild/thread/7e7cb2ed-7636-4761-8e99-655509a4d8ba).

If you need Sharepoint assembly, this [technote describes the requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff622991.aspx).

And I don't think an automatic import utility exists (from TFS2010 to ClearCase 7.1.x), as this [technote mentions](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21228699):

> Change request (RFE) RATLC01005874 had been submitted requesting a conversion utility to export source code from Microsoft Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) to ClearCase;
>   however, the decision was made by Product Management to exclude the requested feature from future upgrades and releases due to the significant architectural changes required to implement the solution.

The right approach is to manage to list the content of [relevant labels for a given scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184096/override-where-a-label-is-created-by-msbuild-in-tfs-2008-2010), and make a [`clearfsimport` into a ClearCase view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164807/what-data-to-collect-for-migrate-code-from-mainframe-to-clearcase/4217217#4217217), with a full label applied right after it.

Comment: There is a toolset I'm referring to right now that's called TFS Integration Tools or Platform. It's on CodePlex and on MS's site. It's specifically designed to allow TFS <=> TFS integration and TFS <=> CC integration. But there is little documentation and most examples only show TFS <=> TFS. I'm having a hard time finding examples of CC use or required software to even install the tool. The codeplex site doesn't seem to be very quick in answering questions.

Comment: @firebellys: `TFS <=> CC` integration? I would recommend to not bother: simply list the relevant labels, and `clearfsimport` them ;) (with the `-rmname` option, in order to have a 'mirror' import between source and destination).

Comment: I think this will be the final solution, as it looks like the tools created by the TFS Rangers for TFS <=> CC isn't what I would call a mature product. Maybe someday? But then again, who ever wants to do this? :) Thanks for the idea, I'll look at that now too.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need TFS (server), VS or SharePoint installed. You will need a SQL server for the core platform. Then you will need the various assemblies for TFS, which you can get by installing the Team Explorer component (it's on the TFS install media).

Comment: I've been working with the tfs rangers on this and I think we have most of it working. The full 2 way sync doesn't seem to be supported, but it looks like one way migrations from TFS => CC should work great. I will update with the results in a few weeks after we get a solid POC going. Not that anyone in the universe would want to recreate a TFS => CC sync....